# Bind function globally through jquery for Session Timeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have an action method in asp.net core which returns whether the session has expired or not. I want the function to run after every 1 hour. But how can I bind it permanently?

If I bind it on a particular page, it will not work because the user may navigate to some other page.

I tried binding it to the window but that also did not work. Binding it on window on-load did not work.

```
public IActionResult IsSessionActive()
    {
    ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("CompanyId") == null)
    {
     response.Data = false;
     response.isError = true;
     response.Message = loc["SessionTimedOut"].Value;
    } 
    else
     {
      response.Data = false;
     }
       return Json(response);
    }

   window.setInterval(IsSessionActive(), 3600000); // jquery code
```

The function IsSessionActive should be bind globally to the web application through jquery and run after every 1 hour.

Comment: Do you develop asp.net core mvc or asp.net core blazor? Did you call `window.setInterval(IsSessionActive(), 3600000); // jquery code` in .razor file or html? Share us how you called this code.

Comment: I called this code in document ready which is placed in a seperate js file. The js file is called in the Index.cshtml file.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would have a "layout" view in your shared folder where there is the footer and your menu, etc.

You can put that kind of logic in there.

It is located in Views > Shared > _LayoutPage.cshtml or some similar name.

Try to execute your script in that view.

I had to face something similar, maybe you can try this and see if this works for you:

- Create a session variable when you log in. The value of that variable should be the actual date and time (DateTime.Now) plus one hour (tha's when you'll need to verify again if your session has expired).
- In your master page, create a SetInverval function that launches an ajax request (every five minutes or so, as you see) to see if the actual date and time is less than your session variable (to see if you need to verify your session). If the date and time is greater than your session variable, then it's time to check again if your session is still valid.
- If it is, reset your session variable time and repeat the process, if not, log out the user.

Comment: But the architecture of ASP.net is that

Comment: 1. Master Page is called

Comment: 2. Detail Page is called. 3. Control is called  So, even if I bind in Layout.cshtml, and if user navigates to some other page, the binding would remove because master page would be called again.